# How to customize Chromium browser from source code

Tags: browser, chrome

Customizing Chromium includes fixing homepage, removing address bar, .etc. Is it possible to modify the source code or using some compiling options to achieve these goals?

Comment: You can certainly try: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but it's a huge task. Chromium, over the years, has become a huge program with a multitude of moving parts that some are having trouble keeping track of. It's a very large undertaking that assumes you have lots of time and talent to put into it.